# Specific SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to find the correct query for this problem but it doesn't quite work so I'm asking here:

I have 2 tables:

Table-1 has 5 rows with 6 attributes each

Table-2 has 3 rows with 5 attributes and EACH attribute corresponds to 1 row from table 1. What I want is a query that will give me all the attributes from table 1 that are contained in table 2. I've come up to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE PrimKey IN
   (SELECT *
    FROM Table2
    WHERE PrimKey = Index)
```

However it won't let me do this because it says that on the second SELECT I can't select all but I have to choose. This way I can only view 1 row of Table1 stuff from Table2 but I want to view all of Table2's attributes.

Comment: The error that you are seeing is because you have more than one field in Table2 and you are using 'SELECT *' in your subquery

Comment: Assuming Muhammed's answer doesn't solve your problem you are going to have to give us some more information. Show us the schema of Table1 and Table2.

Comment: Muhammed's answer isn't what I'm looking for.

Table 1 schema:
PrimKey, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3

Table 2:
PrimKey, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4 
where those attributes have as values the PrimKey of Table 1.

Table 1 is a list of clothes with attributes: color, size etc.
Table 2 is a list of cloth combinations and attributes here are any of the T-1 tuple rows. For example the first row of T2 has as Attr-1:Shirt (the PrimKey of the "Shirt" tuple in table 1), Attr-2:Pants etc.

What I want is by knowing the table 2 PrimKey to get as the result the tuples from table 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE PrimKey IN
   (SELECT PrimKey 
    FROM Table2)
```

**Or INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ReferencingColumn = t2.ReferencingColumn
```